# How to return corresponding items as an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, hashcode

In the below code , I'm trying to implement the method getItemByManufacturer which should return the array of items for the manufacturer we test. I have tried to get the array of items for a particular manufacturer but the hashcode is getting printed. Why is that ? I have overridden the toString method too. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Item{
    
    private long serialNumber;
    private String itemName;
    String manufacturer;
    private int warrantyDays;
    private double rating;

Item( String itemName,String manufacturer,long serialNumber,double rating){
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return itemName +"\t"+manufacturer+"\t\t"+serialNumber+"\t"+rating;
    }


    public static String[] getItemByManufacturer(Item[] item,String manufacturer){
    String[] matchedItems = new String[item.length];
    for(int i =0; i<item.length;i++){
        if(item[i].manufacturer.equals(manufacturer)){
            matchedItems[i] = item[i];
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
    return matchedItems;
}

public class Driver{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Item[] item = new Item[5];
        item[0] = new Item("Watch","Dorond",23945357,6.5);
        item[1] = new Item("Sunglass","Niko",13945357,6.5);
        item[2] = new Item("Blender","Decker",33945357,6.5);
        item[3] = new Item("Bottle","Decker",43945357,6.5);
        item[4] = new Item("Bag","WTravel",53965307,6.5);
        
    
   **System.out.println((Item.getItemByManufacturer(item,"Decker")));**
       
       
       
      
        
       }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because arrays don't have toString method, so you get the hashcode when you print them. A way to print them is by just using an internal java library [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Item.getItemByManufacturer(item,"Decker"));
```

or by converting the array to a List with [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Item.getItemByManufacturer(item,"Decker"));
```

Moreover, notice that you should change the condition `items[i].manufacturer == manufacturer` to `items[i].manufacturer.equals(manufacturer)`, strings must always be compared by using the `equals` method. Also, if the condition matches, you're just returning the entire array, so you won't get the desired result. I suggest this solution, since array are not dynamically sized, is much easier to just return a List:

```
public class Item{
    
    private long serialNumber;
    private String itemName;
    String manufacturer;
    private int warrantyDays;
    private double rating;

Item( String itemName,String manufacturer,long serialNumber,double rating){
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return itemName +"\t"+manufacturer+"\t\t"+serialNumber+"\t"+rating;
    }


    public static List<Item> getItemByManufacturer(Item[] items, String manufacturer){

        List<Item> matchedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for(int i =0; i< items.length;i++){
            if( items[i].manufacturer.equals(manufacturer)){
                matchedItems.add(items[i]);
            }
        }
        if(matchedItems.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        return mathedItems;
    }

public class Driver{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Item[] item = new Item[5];
        item[0] = new Item("Watch","Dorond",23945357,6.5);
        item[1] = new Item("Sunglass","Niko",13945357,6.5);
        item[2] = new Item("Blender","Decker",33945357,6.5);
        item[3] = new Item("Bottle","Decker",43945357,6.5);
        item[4] = new Item("Bag","WTravel",53965307,6.5);
        
    
        System.out.println(Item.getItemByManufacturer(item,"Decker"));
       
       

   }
```

Comment: I already tried using arrays.toString and ArraysasList but it did not give me the required output

Comment: @AllenHay can you show what output are you having?

Comment: [Watch  Dorond          23945357        6.5, Sunglass   Niko            13945357
        6.5, Blender    Decker          33945357        6.5, Bottle     Decker
        43945357        6.5, Bag        WTravel         53965307        6.5]

Comment: I noticed the logic of the code is actually wrong, you're just returning the whole array if the condition matche. I have updated my solution, read it again and give it a try

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using ArrayList but still get the prompt for invalid output? I have to use the normal arrays.

Comment: It would be better to use arraylist, but if you really want arrays, you can create an array with the same size of the original one, fill the elements that are matched and return it

Comment: That's what I did previously, but I could not print the output even using toString or toArrayList. Can you show me how it works ?

Comment: No, that's not what you did previously. Previously, you was just returning the entire array, therefore you were printing the entire array. Instead, you need to create a NEW array with the same size, and fill it when the conditions match

Comment: I have edited my method. Can you check ? I'm getting the error : Item cannot be converted to String because I couldn't make the return type Item[] so i made it String !